# Entity Framework one to many : SqlException

Tags: entity-framework, one-to-many

I have a little problem when I try to save an item in my DB using EntityFramework.

My classes looks like:

```
public partial class Site
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LongName { get; set; }
    public string Adress { get; set; }
    public City City { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; }
    public string VATNumber { get; set; }
}


public class Country
    {
        public int CountryId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string IsoCode { get; set; }
    }
```

And when I try to create a new site in my controller it works, but when I try to add a link to an existing Country :

```
if (SiteProvider.GetSiteByName(Site.Name) == null)
{
   Site.Country = CountryProvider.GetCountryById(1);//it's working, i see the link to the right country
   SiteProvider.Create(Site);
}



 public static void Create(Site Site)
 {
      using (MyDBContext Context = new MyDBContext())
      {
          Context.Site.Add(Site);
          Context.SaveChanges(); //here is the problem
      }
  }
```

I got this error:

> SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in
>   table 'Country' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: check this http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Add `CountryId` property to `Site` class and when adding a new `Site` set `CountryId` instead of `Country` property

```
public int CountryId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("CountryId")]
public Country Country{ get; set; }
```

Comment: This is working like this, but actually, I lose the link to the Country: I just have the Id, so I can't do "MySite.Country.Name" by example, I'll have to search my country from the id to use it

Comment: To load Country you need to use `.Include()` method when querying for e.g. `dbContext.Sites.Include(site => site.Country).ToList()`

Comment: I changed my architecture to have an unit of work, and I used something like you said: `'unitOfWork.SiteRepository.Read(includeProperties: "Country")`
It seems working like that, I'll keep testing it. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You have a slight issue with your use of contexts here.  You have used one DBContext instance to load the country (where this country object will be tracked) and then a second DBContext to save the site (where the first country object is a property).

It is preferable to perform all your operations for a single unit of work by using one DB context (that would be shared between your classes) and the responsibility for disposing of it to be handled outside your repository layer.

Comment: I think the problem come from that yes, I create a DBContext for both actions, I think it's not good. I'll try to change it, thanks for your answere

Comment: (I'm sorry I'm a beginner with EF)
What is the best way to do that? I create a "master" class which create the DBContext, then I make my classes inherits from this one so they can use the DBContext?

Comment: @samumeur - this is too hard to answer without details of your implementation.  I would recommend investigating a dependency injection framework and using that to inject your DBContext where needed.